# Determine whether a `call` event is a class definition in settrace

Tags: python, python-3.x, trace, cpython

When you use `settrace`, you can track `call` events in code execution (among others). However, the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) mentions:

> A function is called (**or some other code block entered**). The global trace function is called; arg is None; the return value specifies the local trace function.

As far as I can tell, there's no foolproof convenient way to tell when an "other" code block is being entered. This is a problem in my use case where I am trying to determine if a class *definition* (not an instantiation) has been entered. I see some ways of querying the `frame.f_code.co_flags` to determine if we are entering a generator, but nothing about classes or anything else that has its own scope.

So far, the only thing I've come up with is based on this [detail](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-55):

> If a code object represents a function, the first item in co_consts is the documentation string of the function, or None if undefined.

So in theory, I could check if the `co_consts` somehow, but I'm not convinced that that will pay off.

I've also been digging through the CPython source code, and I discovered that the class statement is actually apparently just [calling the `__build_class__` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7276ca25f5f1440aa4d025350d3de15141854dde/Python/ceval.c#L2756-L2781), and that is what actually triggers the tracing behavior? I'm not sure if that's correct, or if I missed some other lines of code dedicated to doing it, but then the only reasonable solution seems to be to hook into the [`__build_class__` infrastructure](https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/languages/Python/built-in-functions/__build_class__/index) (which is viable for my use cases).

So [here's the code I came up with](https://gist.github.com/acbart/85554071c48ad3fa0377670a16d07171). But is there a better, more sane way?